# Linear programming using blocking theory R

Tags: r, linear-programming

The following linear programming problem is not of canonical form. I am really stuck when trying to put this in regular form and feed it into the normal `lp()` function.

Does someone has experience with such weird form?

B and A are the blocker and antiblocker, respectively, which are simply two sets of inequalities.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the "normal lp() function" is. Let's assume this is the [lp function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lpSolve/versions/5.6.13.3/topics/lp) from the LpSolve package.

This function does not expect a canonical form. (Canonical usually means each constraint has the same fixed sign, e.g. `Ax<=b`; **lp()** allows different signs for each constraint).

**lp()** just wants one big constraint matrix: each column is an individual variable and each row is an individual constraint. This is conceptual simple, but often tedious in practice. Best thing to do is to get a large piece of paper and draw the layout of the LP matrix: which variables and constraints go where.

For some classes of models there are easier-to-use tools to express an LP model, such as OMPR, CVXR.